# How can i increase number of post on each row in wordpress col-6 module-content grid

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

i am working on a wordpress news theme. On that theme there is sidebar with "col-3"and "col-6 module-content" for news thumb. Now its showing 2 thumb on each row. I want to show 3 thumb on each row. How can i do so? bellow the content.php file of the theme.

```html
<?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying posts
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package Online_News
 */

?>
<div class="col-6 module-content">
 <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

  <?php if( is_sticky() ){ ?>
      <div class="favourite"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></div>
  <?php } ?>

  <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()):?>
   <div class="list-img"> 
     <?php the_post_thumbnail('online-news-feature-thumb');?>
   </div>
  <?php endif;?> 
  <div class="news-content">
   <?php if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) : ?>
    <div class="entry-meta">
     <?php $disable_post_meta = online_news_get_option('disable_postmeta'); 
     if('false'== !$disable_post_meta): ?>
      <?php online_news_posted_on();?>
     <?php endif;?>
      
     <?php $disable_categories = online_news_get_option('disable_categories'); 
     if('false'== !$disable_categories): ?>
      <div class="category-link">        
         <?php online_news_category();?>
       </div>
     <?php endif;?>  
     
    </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    
   <?php endif; ?>    

   <header class="entry-header">
    <?php 

    if ( is_single() ) :
     the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
    else :
     the_title( '<h3 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h3>' );
    endif;
     ?> 
   </header><!-- .entry-header -->
   
   <div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_excerpt();?>
             <?php $readmore_text = online_news_get_option('readmore_text'); ?>
             <a class="more-link" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php  echo esc_html($readmore_text);?></a>
   </div><!-- .entry-content -->   
  </div>
 </article><!-- #post-## -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the div class from `col-6` into `col-4`.

`<div class="col-4 module-content">`

Cheers!

Comment: when i did col-4  each thumb get smaller but still 2 thumb on first row and 3rd thumb on 2nd row . i want 3rd thumb on first row

Comment: in this case, you may need to check the code that loop your post and your css code. it would be better if you can provide the loop code and the css code that handle the column.